# Bash conditionally redirect std. out based on verbosity level

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to implement verbosity level flag so that a command's output executed in my script is shown to stdout only if verbosity level is greater than a certain threshold.

I was able to correctly parse invocation arguments to determine the verbosity level (e.g. -v -> verbosity 1, -vvv -> verbosity 3).
Now I'm not sure how to use. The easiest way I'd do it is something like :

```
if test "$VERBOSE" -gt 2; then
    cmd 1>/dev/null
else
    cmd
fi
```

This solution, although correct, seems to introduce a lot of boiler plate code in my script if for every command I have to repeat that. Is there a better and more concise way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to only redirect certains commands' output

Choose a free file descriptor and redirect it where you want if you want.
Different file descriptors could be associated with different loglevels.

```
if test "$VERBOSE" -gt 2; then
    exec 3>&1
else
    exec 3>/dev/null
fi
certain_command >&3
not_certain_command
```

Another design with a function:

```
log() {
     if test "$VERBOSE" -gt "$1"; then
          shift
          "$@"
     else
          shift
          "$@" >/dev/null
     fi
}
log 3 certain_command_with_logs_at_verbose_greater_then_3
log 1 certain_command_with_logs_at_verbose_greater_then_1
non_certain_command
```

Comment: duh, kind of obvious now that I see it xd, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better and more concise way of achieving the same?

Yes. You could centralize the code in shell functions. This even allows to selectively apply the redirections or not for the same `cmd`.

```
my_cmd () {
   if test "$VERBOSE" -gt 2; then
       cmd "$@" 1>/dev/null
   else
       cmd "$@"
   fi
}
my_cmd -x arg1 arg2
other_cmd
cmd -x foo    # Do not apply redirection this time.
```

PS: this works for all Bourne-heritage shells, so I took the liberty to re-tag your question from bash to shell.

Comment: This would redirect everything that is sent to std. out to /dev/null . I would not be able to lets say echo or output anything. I'd like to only redirect certains commands' output

Comment: @MFranc Ok, I have rewritten my answer to take this into account.